# .find().html() in jquery always returning null when used inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access data of the html document(contains a table) that I am opening in iframe.
I want to access table data.

```
//#we is id of a <td> #iframe is id of iframe
var q=$('#iframe').find('#we').html();
document.write(q);
```

But when i use this i always get a null value.help.

Comment: You can access the content of iframe only if it is from the same domain.

Comment: can you please post your detail code to understand it what you had done.

Comment: the td is inside iframe and it is in same server?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the iframe is on the same domain, otherwise you can't get access to its internals. That would be cross-site scripting.

None of the browsers would allowing accessing iframe which is from a different domain than your site. It is a serious security breach. Thus if you are loading iframe from different domain, no matter what you do, you can't access it.

You might not like the answer, but it is the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is in fact on the same domain - you can use the following.

```
var q = $('#iframe').contents().find('#we').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var body = $('#iframe').contents().find('body');
```

or this can also be helpful:

```
$(editFrame).contents().find("html").html();
```

That should return all the html in the iframe for you. Or you can use "body" or "head" instead of "html" to get those sections too.